# How do I get the cookie values in a backbone.js model?

Tags: html, backbone.js

I have a simple Backbone.js/Bootstrap front end in HTML5 with a Node.js/Restify backend. I am setting cookies in a header response from the server as below:

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["token=ninja", "language=javascript"]);
```

On the client side, I am making a REST call as

```
var response = this.model.fetch().success(function(data){
           //success
           }).error(function(data){
           //error 
           }).complete(function(data){
            //complete
           });
```

that callsback a parse method in the model.

How can I read the cookie value in the model?

Answer (score 1):

Include [Cookie.js](http://code.google.com/p/cookie-js/).

You can then reference individual cookies like this:

```
var token = Cookie.get('token')

# token == 'ninja'
```

Comment: Tried this method...definitly easier but return value is 'null'. See my comment on Brian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I figured out. My application has two components - the HTML/js from one domain that talks to a REST sevice on another domain (and therefore is cross-domain.) Because the cookie is set from REST, it appears is not readable across domains. So the web page will not store the cookie even though the server is sending it. One alternative is to use local cookies or use the technique illustrated by http://backbonetutorials.com/cross-domain-sessions/.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery with Backbone, you can get the headers by defining the `parse` function in your model by calling `getAllResponseHeaders` or `getResponseHeader`:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // the rest of your model

    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        var allHeaders = xhr. getAllResponseHeaders();
        var cookieHeader = xhr. getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");

        // do something with the headers

        return resp;
    }
});
```

Comment: Odd.  I wonder if jQuery is pulling out cookies and adding them to the  `document.cookie` property?  Have you tried the anser by @Martin Cortez ?

Comment: This works but does not return the cookie values.

allHeader returns - 
X-Request-Id: e865bb4a-5405-41ab-b273-2275d822eb39
X-Response-Time: 812
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 May 2012 16:02:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

cookieHeader returns null.

Fiddler shows the cookie values.

Comment: This is the fiddler return (removed some headers from below for brevity)  - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: token=ninja
Set-Cookie: language=javascript
ETag: myETag
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Api-Version, X-Request-Id, X-Response-Time
Content-MD5: mzMEDkkQr0FeqHBLnLrQ7g==
Date: Wed, 23 May 2012 16:13:42 GMT
X-Request-Id: 1d7ddf6f-51ed-43ed-9ecf-e66768923be7
X-Response-Time: 795

Comment: Tried Martin's method as well..same result 'null' returned.